# How to program collaboratively with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cvs, code-sharing

I'm in a team programming project with 2 other students and we're all using Eclipse. It seems to have sharing features which would could be a big help to us. I started to setup a CVN, but then it got all confusing when I had to enter a host name. What should I put in there? I'm on a Macbook Pro. I'm just on a DSL connection. Is it possible to get this to work? Do I have to setup some additional server software?

Answer (score 1):

Just a word of warning: Steer clear of CVS!

SVN (Subversion, is good enough, will be excellent for your project, as it's not too difficult to get your head around it. There's a lot of talk about git, it sounds great, but comes with a somewhat steeper learning curve. I have been thinking about switching from SVN to git, but I just don't have any motivation for that. There have been people at our company investigating whether we should all start using git for our big enterprise-level projects but these came with a conclusion that it's just not worth the trouble getting a whole lot of people to adopt new practices. So SVN is my suggestion.

Currently, for my pet projects I am using a free account on Beanstalk.com they are hosting the repository for you and all you need is a subclipse plugin for your eclipse and it will not matter what platform you are running on you mac/pc you will be able to work collaboratively on your project without too much difficulty. Just create new repository, check out from it, add files, check them in. Update before you start working, update and commit before you've finished.

Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use Git.. it is hosted, free and relatively easy. If you setup your own SVN, CVS or other source management system you will have to maintain it. If you screw it up you'd probably lose some work at the least or the entire project.

...and lastly, Git will be everywhere the internet is